# awk string manipulation

Tags: awk

I am trying to manipulate a string using `awk`.

Input

```
ABCD|98855.9849:122,9440.9886:3434|TEST
```

Output

```
ABCD|98855.9849:122,9440.9886:3434|TEST|122
```

I tried the command below

```
echo "ABCD|9885.9849:122,9440.9886:3434|TEST" |
    awk -F"|" '{print $1"|"$2"|"$3"|"system("echo "$2"|awk -F[:,] '{print $2}'")}'
```

but I get

```
awk: {print $1"|"$2"|"$3"|"system("echo "$2"|awk -F[:,] {print
awk:                          ^ unterminated string
```

How to do it?

Comment: want everything in one command

Comment: So all you want to do is to append the number found after the `:` to the end of the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done within a single `awk` using the `split()`  function:

```
$ awk -F"|" -v OFS="|" '{split($2, arr, "[,:]"); print $1, $2, $3, arr[2]}' input
ABCD|9885.9849:122,9440.9886:3434|TEST|122
```

- `-v OFS="|"` sets the output field separator, so I can do `print $1, $2, ...` without having to specify the `|` each time.
- `split($2, arr, "[;,]")` splits the contents of `$2` into the array `arr`, using the separator regex `[,:]` (just like `FS`).

Comment: Thanks Elayne - your answer helped me and I appreciate it.